# My apk weighs 150 mb, is there any way to reduce this?

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, proguard, jitsi

I've been working on my flutter app for about two months now and the size was around and average 0f 30 - 35 mb when compiling an apk, recently I added the flutter jitsi_meet 1.0.0 dependency and now when I compile an my apk size turns out to be 156 mb.
**Is it posible that the dependency is that heavy?**
**and if so, Is it posible to reduce it?**

I ran their main.dart example and then compiled it and turn out to be 98 mb on a fat apk.

Answer (score 2):

this plugin uses video handing thing this is why size increased. use split APK run this command

```
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your release mode app size for that run below two commands on your terminal.

```
1. flutter clean
2. flutter build apk
```

Also, Google Play allows us to upload multiple apks, e.g. one per every architecture.

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Follow the instruction here: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release

Answer (score 0):

First, run this command

```
flutter clean
```

Then the build command